# Sitecore lucene greek search is accent sensitive?

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore8, accent-insensitive

On a default Sitecore 8 installation, I have a bucket with quite a few items in it. When I issue a content search query on a RTE field in the Greek language, it seems that Sitecore treats the search term in an accent sensitive way, which is wrong for Greek.

Can someone point me to the right direction into making the index accent insensitive for Greek?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue was with the way Sitecore understands cultures and assigns culture execution context to its searches and indexes.

For the particular solution, we had renamed the "el-GR" language to "el" (to show "nicely" in the url). In turn, Sitecore was assigning a CultureInfo with name "el", not "el-GR". But in the defaultIndexConfiguration config file, the Greek analyzer would be assigned only when the CultureInfo of the CultureExecutionContext was el-GR, so the data was actually indexed using the StandardAnalyzer, not the GreekAnalyzer, hence the accent sensitivity.

We added extra config to cover the case where the CultureInfo has name "el" (copied the "el-GR" config node actually) and after the necessary index rebuild, everything was OK.

It is rather obscure though why Sitecore would go and alter the name of the CultureInfo object...

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to change your analyzer.  Two good options come to mind for this case, as far as how to analyze it:

- Use [`org.apache.lucene.analysis.el.GreekAnalyzer`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_1_0/analyzers-common/index.html?org/apache/lucene/analysis/el/GreekAnalyzer.html).  This will do what you're asking for, as well as add Greek language stemming.  This is probably the best option, unless you really don't want stemming.
- Create a custom analyzer that uses [`GreekLowerCaseFilter`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_1_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/el/GreekLowerCaseFilter.html), instead of the standard lowercase filter.  This filter will remove diacritics and the like, so I believe it will do what you are looking for:

  ```java
  public class StandardWithGreekLower extends StopwordAnalyzerBase{
      public StandardWithGreekLower() {
      }

      @Override
      protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(final String fieldName) {
          StandardTokenizer src = new StandardTokenizer();
          TokenStream filter = new StandardFilter(src);
          filter = new GreekLowerCaseFilter(filter);
          //If you want to add a stop filter, this would be a good place for it
          return new TokenStreamComponents(src, filter);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Ah, I should have made it clearer that this is a lucene.NET question. Also, I can verify that I am indeed using the Greek analyzer, because that's what the "default Sitecore 8 installation" does - assigns the Greek analyzer when the culture is identified as Greek.